# How to hibernate entity ManyToOne join without primary key

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I am trying to do a ManyToOne join where there are 2 values needed to define the relationship.  I have an Person table with a unique key and an business related id number.  In the address table, the relationship is defined by id number, not the unique key.  Person is unique with a combination of id number and a column marking it as active.

I am using jboss 4.2.3, and hibernate 3.2.4.

If this was a unique key, I would be doing it like this within the Address entity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name ="PERSON_ID")
private Person person;
```

Basically I want to run this same join, but with another specification that Person ACTIVE = 'Y'.

I have seen things like using a filter or where, but I have been unable to get them to work.  I have also seen examples where you can use multiple join columns, but this is a fixed value and do not want it stored in the table as a column.